# Why Map api doesn't provide stream capabilities in Java?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I agree we can get entrySet on any Map and then create a stream of it. But still I'm wondering what must be the reason behind not giving stream capabilities to Map hierarchy in Java 8.

Comment: A stream is a stream of **elements**. What are the elements of a Map? The Keyset? The Valueset? The Entryset? From this point of view, I find it quite sensible to stream over the respective set one needs.

Comment: The same reason why you can’t loop over a `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

The stream API lets you process a single element in abstracted fashion (parallel, sequential, generated on the fly, infinite supply, yadayada).

A map has 2 elements per 'item' (a key, *and* a value).

Either every method that stream has needs to be adapted to take 2 args, or, we reuse all the infrastructure that the stream API offers by letting you stream through `Map.Entry` items, which are a single element.

Then the question boils down to: Why isn't there some syntax sugar / API shortcut so that I can write `map.stream()` instead of `map.entrySet().stream()`. That's because java prefers such a choice to not be implicit: You want to stream over the entries? Okay.. write that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just imagine there is method **stream** in Map. 
So it should return a Stream of key and value at the same time, right?
And as BiStream is not introduced yet (unsure it will be ever), so the only possibility is to wrap both into single object (Entry?). But stream of entries you can get from an entrySet as you already declared. 
So adding a such method with simple delegation to entrySet does not sound really reasonable.